# Getting "This site can’t be reached" after launching the hub using docker

Tags: linux, selenium, docker, centos7

Below are the steps I followed:

1. Access Linux server using putty from Windows 7
2. Run `docker run -d -P -p 4545:4444 --name standalone_grid  selenium/standalone-chrome` on Linux
3. Launch chrome browser on windows and try to access
   `http://<linux_server_ip>:4545`. Error site can't be reached. This server also has Jenkins installed which can be accessed at `http://<linux_server_ip>:8080`

How can I fix this? Am I doing anything wrong?

`docker ps` **out put**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
60422c2cd9b1        selenium/standalone-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:4545->4444/tcp   standalone_grid
```

Comment: Is the container still running?  Are firewall rules on the server blocking inbound requests?  Is the server inside the container listening on port 4444?

Comment: `Is the container still  running?` to verify this I executed `docker ps -a` and I see the container. To double check I stop it `docker stop <container name>` and restart it and again I see it below `docker ps -a`

Comment: @jww I don't agree with you, but I like that  you downvoted and showed yourself up. Mostly people just downvote and run away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments first thing you want to check if the container is up:

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b7a560331584        selenium/standalone-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:4545->4444/tcp   standalone_grid
```

Next step would be just to verify locally is it working from the Linux console:

```
curl http://<linux_server_ip>:4545
```

If this works you already know it is a networking issue. Please check your local iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT
```

to see if there are any restrictions for incoming connections. If this is empty the the issue lays in connectivity within the network itself. You can try to workaround it by using a Putty [ssh tunnel](https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/4/how-to-configure-an-ssh-tunnel-on-putty).

EDIT:

The issue was related to port 4545, using a different port resolved the problem.

Comment: I have added what `docker ps` is giving. Looks like `4545` is redirecting to `4444`. So I tried both curl `http://<linux_server_ip>:4545` and `http://<linux_server_ip>:4444`. Where `http://<linux_server_ip>:4545` gave timeout and `http://<linux_server_ip>:4444` gave `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: SSH on port 4444? perhaps there is some conflict in terms of used ports, can you run: `netstat -lntp | egrep '4545|4444'`

Also you can check if the service is working fine directly inside of the container:
`docker exec -ti ${CONTAINER ID} curl http://localhost:4444`

Comment: `sudo netstat -lntp | egrep '4545|4444'` it gives nothing and `docker exec -ti ${60422c2cd9b1} curl http://localhost:4444` gives `Error: No such container: curl`

Comment: you need to remove ${} so the right command will be: `docker exec -ti 60422c2cd9b1 curl http://localhost:4444`

Comment: This time `docker exec -ti 60422c2cd9b1 curl http://localhost:4444` command worked and gave xml.

Comment: that means container is fine, the problem then is with your linux system and specific port 4545, normally after running netstat you should see: `sudo netstat -lntp | egrep '4545|4444'
tcp6       0      0 :::4545                 :::*                    LISTEN      8449/docker-proxy`

can you try running the container on a different high port i.e. `docker run -d -P -p 51842:4444 --name standalone_grid  selenium/standalone-chrome`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187337/discussion-between-paul-and-dongi).